# ERROR SYNTAX: perhaps you forgot the comma?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, python-import

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NAFa.png)

this part has an error:

file name: uiux.py

```
import main 
from main import generate_click

B_resi = tk.Button(window, text="Generate Number",command=main.generate_click)
B_resi.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=10,pady=10,sticky='e')
```

file name: main.py

```
import mysql.connector
import uiux

dbc = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = 'localhost'
    user = 'user'
    password = '6Vmv-Jl/Sba4F9jM',
    database = 'belajar_barang'
)

if dbc.is_connected:
    print("Database Terkoneksi")
else:
    print("Cek Koneksi Database!")

cursor = dbc.cursor()

def generate_click():
    tempcust = uiux.custID.get()[:3]
    print(tempcust)
```

how to solve those problems?

I don't know where are the problems, please help me..

edit:
the first problem is solved, thank you.

this is my new problem, I don't understand
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VCtT.png)

Comment: On line 5 (`host = 'localhost'`) it looks like you are missing a comma, and this should be `host = 'localhost',` to ensure each of the arguments are separated by a comma (a bit like you have already done after the password on line 7.

Comment: Look at the error message, it is telling you "(`main.py`, line 5)". If you try running `main.py`, I bet that VSCode will even tell you that it's supposed to be at the end of line 5. Python tells you about the errors, you just have to read what python is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here in main.py:

```
dbc = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = 'localhost',  # missing comma
    user = 'user',  # missing comma
    password = '6Vmv-Jl/Sba4F9jM',
    database = 'belajar_barang',  # you technically don't need a comma here
    # but it's good practice should you decide to add other kwargs
)
```